# jQuery onclick add textbox value to div using the ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add some textbox value to some other divs.
What I'd like to obtain is somthing like this:

```
textbox id = "text-box-name-1"   ----> div id = "div-name-1"
textbox id = "text-box-name-2"   ----> div id = "div-name-2"
textbox id = "text-box-name-3"   ----> div id = "div-name-3"
and so on....
```

How can i do this? mind that the number of divs and textboxes are dynamically generated.!

Any suggestion will be really appreciated.
Thanks

**EDIT**

```
 function test() {
            var rooms = $("#howmanyrooms").val();
            var roomcounter = 1;

            for (var i = 0; i < rooms; i++) {
                $("<div class='appendeddiv'>Room-" + roomcounter++ + "</div>").appendTo(".housecontainer");
                $("<span>Room-" + roomcounter + " name</span>&nbsp;<input type='text' placeholder='name' id='room-" + roomcounter + "-id'></div></br>").appendTo(".infoncontainer");
            };
            if ($('.housecontainer').find('.appendeddiv').length) {
                $("#buttonaddrooms").hide();
            }
        };
```

i have already this code that allows me to create as many divs and textboxes as i type inside the textbox as value.

Now, i want be able to set, for example as div title, what the user type inside the textbox, and the only way that i've thought till now is using the id that are dynamically generated by the code that i already have.

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear to me.

Comment: We like to help people, not to work for them for free. Show us some effort.

Comment: no, cause i don't know neither where to start
Thats why i asked any suggestion...
I'm not asking for code, but at least a start point to do this...
I'm new using jquery

Comment: Well if you need a start point then surely you'l get it here. Please let us know what you want exactly? do you want to add Div and Textboxes dynamically? Or Those are already present and you just need values to be added in those?

Comment: In case you need to generate structure like you mentioned. then you have to iterate through one loop where you can create $("<div> class='row'").append("<input type="textbox"/>) and write this to any target container...........

Comment: @KD please check the edit on the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for editing the post...

I would suggest first to add one class as an identifier to the Textbox and Div so we can attach event with the help of jQuery

```
$("<div class='appendeddiv targetDiv_"+ roomcounter +"'>Room-" + roomcounter + "</div>").appendTo(".housecontainer");
$("<span>Room-" + roomcounter + " name</span>&nbsp;<input type='text' placeholder='name' id='room-" + roomcounter + "-id' lang='textInput' class='targetText_"+ roomcounter +"'></div></br>").appendTo(".infoncontainer");
```

After that following script will do the trick :)

```
<script type='text/javascript>
$(function(){
    $("input.textInput").on("keyup",function(){
    var target = $(this).attr("lang").replace("Text", "Div");
    $("."+target).text($(this).val());
  });
});
</script>
```

**As per your fiddle If you want to update value mannualy onclick of any button then write this method.**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function update(){
   $("input.textInput").each(function(){
     var target = $(this).attr("lang").replace("Text", "Div");
     $("."+target).text($(this).val());
   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...
I tried with your code but i think that i'm doing something wrong cause it doesn't work and i have no error on the chrome console..

Comment: Well FYI, these identifiers are needed because your textbox and associated Divs are not closer to each other and there position is unknown in given html. Otherwise if we could have idea that those are located near by one another then we can remove these identifiers and try to locate them using jquery helpers ... Still i have tried to minimize the code as well as maintainability

Comment: do you mind to create a jsfillde so that i can check what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Well that will take bit more effort and time.. rather i would appreciate if you create a fiddle and let me know what issue you are getting... :) I will look at your code and try to find the threat

Comment: I have updated the fiddle and have updated the code accordingly. Now it should change the value of div on change of text box. Also if you need the update function and want to change the values on click of update button, then don't bind the event which i have mentiond, instead of that just iterate through each textbox element like $("input.textInput").each(function(){/*function body*/}); and place those two line of code in body

Comment: did you save the changes?
Cause i cannot see any difference in the jsfiddle

Comment: This is my new version where you can find code with update function
http://jsfiddle.net/CPzez/5/
And this is your version where i have automated the updation
http://jsfiddle.net/h7LAR/12/ .............Cheers :)

Comment: thank you very much! this is awesome and it worked just as i want!
Cheers

Comment: Please mark it as answer if you got the solution. Cheers

Comment: just another little thing...is it possible to automatically change also the content of the span? so that it will be the same as the div text?

Comment: Yeah use the same logic as we used for divs, Now you can make that bit surely :)